# How to remove leading zeros from a variable?

Tags: bash

I am trying to remove all the zeros in front of a variable in bash. But I am not able to save it in the variable. Some help

the problem is here: `if (( $line > $lastMin )) ; then`

a Bash error run because value too large for the base (the error element is "0455233")

That's why I'm trying to save that value by removing all the zeros I find in front of me

Any solutions please?

```
lastMin=0455233
zeroMin=$(( $lastMin | sed 's/^0*//' ))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing all leading `0`'s;

```
lastMin='0000455233'
zeroMin=$(echo "$lastMin" | sed 's/^0*//')

echo "$zeroMin"   # output : 455233
```

Your problem is caused by using `$((` instead of `$(`, and not `echo`'ing the old var.

Comment: This breaks if `lastMin` is set to just `0`.

Answer (score 5):

```
lastMin='0455233'
zeroMin=$((10#$lastMin))
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to spawn a separate process for this, just use [parameter expansions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02):

```
$ a=01234
$ b=00001234
$ c=1234
$
$ echo "${a#${a%%[1-9]*}}"
1234
$ echo "${b#${b%%[1-9]*}}"
1234
$ echo "${c#${c%%[1-9]*}}"
1234
```

`${var%%[1-9]*}` will remove longest suffix beginning with a digit between 1 and 9 from `var`; so it will leave leading zeroes, and now that you have leading zeroes you can remove them from `var` using `${var#${var%%[1-9]*}}`.

Answer (score 2):

The arithmetic expansion `$(( ... ))` is for, well, arithmetics. The `|` is "binary OR" operation inside `$(( ... ))`.

You just want to pipe the variable value to stdout of another command, ex. `sed`.

On posix compatible shells you can use a simple pipe `|` with process substitution `$()`:

```
zeroMin=$(printf "%s\n" "$lastMin" | sed 's/^0*//')
# or a little tiny bit less portable version with echo
zeroMin=$(echo "$lastMin" | sed 's/^0*//')
```

On bash you can use use here strings `<<<`:

```
zeroMin=$(<<<$lastMin sed 's/^0*//')
```