# Remove leading zeros in Ansible variable

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

How do you remove leading zeros from a ansible variable via ansible?

From [How to remove leading zeros from a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56459428/how-to-remove-leading-zeros-from-a-variable)
I would like to run the following functionality, but I'm unable to get it to run.

```
$ a=01234
$ b=00001234
$ c=1234
$
$ echo "${a#${a%%[1-9]*}}"
1234
$ echo "${b#${b%%[1-9]*}}"
1234
$ echo "${c#${c%%[1-9]*}}"
1234
```

My Attempt is:

```
- shell: "echo ${% raw -%}{{% endraw -%}{{mpp_number_with_leading_zeros}}#${% raw -%}{{% endraw -%}{{mpp_number_with_leading_zeros}}%%[1-9]*{% raw -%}}{% endraw -%}{% raw -%}}{% endraw -%}"
```

Im using ansible 2.9

Answer (score 3):

You could cast the variable with `int` plugin as below:

```yaml
  vars:
    var1: "01234"
    var2: "00001234"
    var3: "1234"

  tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ item }}"
    with_items:
      - "{{ var1 }}"
      - "{{ var2 }}"
      - "{{ var3 }}"
      - "{{ var1 | int }}"
      - "{{ var2 | int }}"
      - "{{ var3 | int }}"
```

Documentation:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#forcing-the-data-type